# writing a custom dataset to pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I am having data of numpy arrays with shape `(400, 46, 55, 46)` here 400 are the samples and `46,55,46` is the image.350 samples for training and remaining 50 for validation

```py
np.max(data[1]), np.min(data[1]), len(data[1])
Output: (2941.0, -43.0, 46)
```

Now i want to load the data into pytorch model for that i need to write a custom dataloader as i am new to pytorch i am finding hard to wrie can someone help

Comment: What do you mean by *"`46,55,46` is the image"*, could you be more specific?

Comment: @Ivan It contains a numpy array which is a 4D tensor, the first dimension is the number of samples and the remaining 3 dimensions are down-sampled image sizes from original size of `182X218X182`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`torch.utils.data.TensorData`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset) and [`torch.utils.data.random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) to construct the two datasets and wrap them with [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader):

```
>>> data = np.random.rand(400, 46, 55, 46)

# Datasets initialization
>>> ds = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(data))
>>> train_ds, valid_ds = random_split(ds, (350, 50))

# Dataloader wrappers
>>> train_dl, valid_dl = DataLoader(train_ds), DataLoader(valid_ds)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is their no need of using `torch.utils.data.Dataset ` ?.

Comment: What if i want to add transformation like normalization e.t.c. TensorDataset does not take transformations

Comment: Then you would need to implement a dataset yourself extending `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. You can find more information [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset).